# Django admin - Create a edit button for each row

Tags: python, django, button, django-admin

I have to create a django admin button that makes each row of my table editable(after i click the button). And then save the edited row without redirecting to any page.

To be 100% clear: when clicking 'edit' all fields in that row will be editable. 
1 edit button per row.

django admin image:
https://gyazo.com/def02a6ed68ddc2e777c0daaf26a0c5d

my admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Remedio
from django.contrib.admin import AdminSite


class MyAdminSite(AdminSite):
    site_header = 'Farmacia'

class RemedioAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
        (None, {'fields': ['descricao']}),
        (None, {'fields': ['data_de_fabricacao']}),
        (None, {'fields': ['data_de_validade']}),
        (None, {'fields': ['manipulado']}),
        (None, {'fields': ['maioridade']}),
        (None, {'fields': ['preco']}),
        (None, {'fields': ['faca_editar']}),

    ]

    list_display = ('descricao', 'data_de_fabricacao', 'data_de_validade', 'preco', 'maioridade', 'manipulado', 'faca_editar')
    list_filter = ['preco']
    search_fields = ['descricao', 'preco']
    list_editable = ['preco']
    list_display_links = ['data_de_fabricacao']
    # readonly_fields = ['preco']


    def make_price_zero(self, request, queryset):
        queryset.update(preco=0.00)
    make_price_zero.short_description = "Marque os remedios que queira zerar o preco"

    actions = ['make_price_zero']

admin.site.register(Remedio, RemedioAdmin)
admin_site = MyAdminSite(name='farmacia_vitu')
```

my models.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models

class Remedio(models.Model):
    descricao = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    data_de_fabricacao = models.DateTimeField()
    data_de_validade = models.DateTimeField()
    imagem = models.ImageField()
    maioridade = models.BooleanField()
    manipulado = models.BooleanField()
    preco = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=8)
    faca_editar = models.URLField()


    def __str__(self):
        return self.descricao
```